# Create Android Input Form from JSON

Tags: android, json, forms

How can I create an android form input on-the-fly from a json string that looks like this:

```
[
   {"Name":"Fullname", "Type":"Text", "List":{""}},
   {"Name":"Age", "Type":"Number", "List":{""}},
   {"Name":"Gender", "Type":"Combo", "List":{"Male","Female"}}
]
```

You may ask why not just insert the input forms inside the app, the reason behind this is the input fields will change from time to time and I do not want to rebuild the android app to add or remove a field every time the form fields is updated. I also want the app to have the ability of just one-time downloading the input fields and use it offline by saving the input in another json file and have the capability to post this json file using a sync button when the user is back online.

EDIT: I have 2 problems: 
1. How to get and store the json string in the phone after the api get call for offline use. 
2. How to create input forms dynamically from the stored json string.

Comment: So you know already how to generate input forms on the fly? And the only problem is reading that json text?

Comment: @greenapps actually those 2 are the problems, please see the updated question.

Comment: Well put that in your post. As it is not clear now. Thats why i asked.

Comment: @greenapps yes the question is updated now, Thanks

Comment: No. You are not stating that you dont know how to create forms on the fly. You still suggest it has something to do withparsing  json.

Comment: If you know how to parse a json text then you do not even have to mention that json as you would know all inputs already.

Comment: @greenapps you need to read closer my friend

Comment: you want to make json input like your Json?

Answer (score 4):

1. How to get and store the json string in the phone after the api get call for offline use.

once you get the json you can save it in SharedPreferences, and for offline use you can get string and convert it to json

```
// to save json
editor.putString("jsondata", jobj.toString());
// to get json for offline use 
String strJson = sharedPref.getString("jsondata","0");
if(strJson != null) JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(strJson);
```

2. How to create input forms dynamically from the stored json string.

For Creating dynamic forms u need to parse json depending on that you can create form

this example will help you creating dynamic form -  http://androidexample.com/Dynamically_Create_View_Elements__-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=115&aaid=137